# Testfor team score not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm developing a Minecraft mini-game and I want to execute a command when a team reach 0 points.

I've created a dummy objective:

```
/scoreboard objective add health dummy Health
```

And 3 teams:

```
/scoreboard teams add A-team teama
/scoreboard teams add B-team teamb
/scoreboard teams add C-team teamc
```

All teams start with 1000 points and depending what they do their points will be decreased, I want to execute a command when one team reachs 0 points. I'm using this but it doesn't work:

```
/testfor @a[team=A-team, score_health_min=0]
```

- I'm using **Minecraft 1.9.1**

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Teams themselves can't have points. Do you mean detecting when someone on that team reaches 0 points, when everyone on that team reaches 0 points, or do you have a fake player set up to represent the team?

Comment: No, teams haven't got any players, Mmm.. So should I add a fake player for each team to represent the team?

Comment: How are you currently adding/subtracting points? You'll need to add a fake player if you haven't already got something set up for that, yeah.

Comment: I use `/scoreboard players remove A-team health 1` to substract points and for add, the same but replacing remove for add. Oh, ok it's the first time i'm developing a mini-game, how could I do that?

Comment: That looks like you're already accidentally using a fake player. You're adding/removing score from a player with the username "A-team" (they could be called anything), when they're not logged in/don't exist. That player isn't the team "A-team" and isn't in the team, even though they happen to have the same name as the team. If the person with the username "A-team" were to join (`-` isn't valid for creating usernames, so it's fine in this case), then the fake player scores you've added/removed would belong to them. I'll write an answer for how to test for fake player scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test for the scores of the fake player you have representing the team, you'll need to use the `/scoreboard players test` command. This is because normal selectors (`@a`, `@p`, etc.) only select players that are online (`/say @a` won't say players who are offline or don't exist, for example).

The syntax for this command is:

```
/scoreboard players test <player> <objective> <min> [max]
```

So, for your example, you'll probably want to do:

```
/scoreboard players test A-team health 0 0
```

You can use conditional command blocks to run a command when this succeeds:

[image]